# Onkeypress never work with any key

Tags: javascript, events

I can't understand why this event never work. "p" is my object, and this event work with onclick but never with onkeypress, onkeydown etc...

```
<rect width="20" height="100" x="900" y="195" onkeypress="p.moverpala(evt)" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />


   moverpala(evt) {
  this.x = evt.keyCode;
  if (this.x == 37) {
      console.log("You pressed the left arrow!");
  }
}
```

Comment: User can click directly on the element, which is why onclick works, but how would that element get the keyboard focus?

Comment: Thanks a lot of for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are not preventing events from bubbling up to your HTML element, I'm guessing you need to focus your element first before you can receive onkeypress events on it.

As alternative you could register keypress events on document element.

Comment: Thanks a lot of for your help